# AngularJS angular-seed GET Status Code: 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-seed

This is my  web.js
For some reason, I can't access http://localhost:8000/app/

```
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8000);

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: is there a directory named `app` inside of the directory `__dirname + '/app'`?

Comment: @Luca yeah. There is. It used to work but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @georgeawg when I do npm start, I get:  > angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart /Users/xxx/Documents/Github/projectname
> npm install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall /Users/xxx/Documents/Github/projectname
> bower install

up to date in 1.777s

> angular-seed@0.0.0 start /Users/xxx/Documents/Github/projectname
> node web.js

Listening on port 8000

Comment: @georgeawg on my developper tool, i get Request URL: http://localhost:8000/app/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade